# How do i achieve the hover effect on button using jquery?

Tags: jquery

i am trying to make the drill down menu with back button using jquery for that i want to achieve the hover effect on button,for that i am using following jquery code-

```
     <script type="text/javascript">    
         $(function(){
               $('#hierarchy').menu({
                     content: $('#hierarchy').next().html(),
                     crumbDefaultText: ' '
               });

               $('#hierarchycrumb').menu({
                      content: $('#hierarchycrumb').next().html(),
                      backLink: false
               });
        });
```

Comment: Need some html, and a link to the plugin you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code....
    $('.fg-button').hover(function(){ $(this).removeClass('ui-state-default').addClass('ui-  state-focus'); },
    );

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to achieve hover functionality with jQuery you can use something like:

```
$('#hierarchy').hover(function(){
 // Do something here
});
```

Or maybe you could explain more precisely what you are trying to do, can't make up much context with the code example.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using CSS to define your button style for the hover state.

```
button:hover{
 color: #aaa;
 /*insert desired styles*/
}
```